# AutoCompleteDecorator is interrupting ItemListener

Tags: java, swing, combobox, swingx, itemlistener

I have an `editable` `JComboBox` which is integrated with the `AutoCompleteDecorator` of `SwingX` library. My `JComboBox` is also having an `ItemListener` registered to it as well. Now, Please have a look at the below code.

```
AutoCompleteDecorator.decorate(ClientNameCombo);
ClientNameCombo.addItemListener(new ClientNameComboAction());

private class ClientNameComboAction implements ItemListener
     {

        @Override
        public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) 
        {
            String selectedClientName= ClientNameCombo.getSelectedItem().toString();


            if(!selectedClientName.equals("Select Client"))
            {
                int idClient = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(client_name_id_map.get(selectedClientName)));

                String sql = "r";


            }
        }
     }
```

No matter what, my code do not pass `int idClient = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(client_name_id_map.get(selectedClientName)));` it always ended up with `NumberFormatException`. The amazing thing is, if I remove `AutoCompleteDecorator` then everything works fine.

Anyone know how to fix this please?

Comment: Try to print (or watch in a debugger) `client_name_id_map.get(selectedClientName)` before the call to parseInt, to see what it contains.

Comment: Are you using a `Map<String, Integer>`? Another dumb question, are the client IDs numeric (in case you are using something other than a `Number` object for the value)?

Comment: You are correct. It is `Map<String, Integer>`. Id's are numeric.

Answer (score 0):

The problem would occur when the key you are looking for is not found in the map.

In such case :

- `client_name_id_map.get(selectedClientName)` would return null
- `String.valueOf(client_name_id_map.get(selectedClientName))` would return "null"
- and `Integer.parseInt("null")` would throw an exception

A simple solution :

```
        if(!selectedClientName.equals("Select Client"))
        {
            Integer idClient = client_name_id_map.get(selectedClientName);
            if (idClient != null) {
                // do something
            }

            String sql = "r";
        }
```